# Form passing String instead of Float

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, view, methods

I have a before_save method on a model that make some calculations with 2 attributes, when I submmit my form I got the error:

```
TypeError in AntropometricasController#create

can't convert String into Integer
```

I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.9

EDIT: Solved this problem by removing the before_save and running the method on the create action (dont know if its correct):

```
@evaluation.calc_imc(@evaluation.value1.to_f,@evaluation.value2.to_f)
```

On my model the method is:

```
attr_accessor :imc
def calc_imc(value1,value2)
  imc = value1/(value2*value2)
end
```

But my `evaluation.imc` is nil. I want to display this value on a view, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** Solved my problem, I was using `@evaluation.calc_imc(@evaluation.value1.to_f,@evaluation.value2.to_f)`, just moved to the view and it worked

Comment: pants down, show us your code baby

Comment: Insufficient data. Can't tell where you're setting it and where you're checking it, etc. As danontheline says, need to see some code for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that assignment of value to imc can define local variable instead of assigning value to the object`s property.

Just replace `imc = value1/(value2*value2)` with `self.imc = value1/(value2*value2)`:

```
def calc_imc(value1,value2)
  self.imc = value1/(value2*value2)
end
```

Comment: Nope, have a nil value even with the self.imc